# Number of the element is not working properly

Tags: jquery

I am creating path elements and adding to a group. Here i don't want to create and add path with same id to the group. so i am skipping the creation and addition of path if 'id' is before used as below

```
drawPath: function (options, groupElement) {
        if ($("#" + options.id).length > 0) { 
          break;
        }
        else {
            var path = document.createElementNS(this.svgLink, "path");
            $(path).attr(options).appendTo(element);
        }

    },


here the options is the attribute to be set for the path and element is the group element to which the path is added  



options = {
                'id': '23+',
                'd': 'M 0 2 L 3 5'
            };
```

the options is varying for each path.

when id is '23+' or '23 Above', $("#" + options.id).length is always showing 0, even when the 2nd path id is '23+'. But i don't want to add more than one path with same id.

```
I am getting this problem only when the id is having special character and white space.
```

Where i am doing wrong

Thanks in advance

Comment: `id` attributes starting with numbers are problematic (even in HTML5), so I would recommend you add a text prefix.

Answer (score 3):

This `#23+` will not get parsed as a jquery selector, since `+` is a meta-character. you have to escape that `+` symbol in order to make it as a valid selector.

Try to change your json like,

```
options = {
           'id': '23\\+',
           'd': 'M 0 2 L 3 5'
          };
```

please read **[here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)** to know about the meta-characters in jquery and how can we use that as a selector.